# how do i add a link to a background image on html body tag

Tags: html, hyperlink

on this [page](http://gioventu.nyc) i have a background image on the `<body>` tag and i'm wondering if it's possible to add a link to it so it clicks through to something.

if this isn't possible, how would i add a wrapper `<div>` that would be hyperlinked?

```
<body id="index">
</body>

body#index {
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(//) !important;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
```

Comment: y dont you use jquery , so that you can add event listener for body. is that possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if this is what you want

```
 <body id="index">

    </body>
```

**CSS**

```
body#index {

    background-color: red !important;

    width:100vw;

    height: 100vh;

}
```

**Jquery**

```
$('body').click(function () {
    location.href="http://www.google.com";
})
```

[fiddled here](https://jsfiddle.net/iamshajeer/L67rytxa/)

try this